# How to convert a hex encoded string to an integer in MS SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, hash, cryptography, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to convert a piece of a hash string returned by the HASHBYTES (SHA2_256) function to an integer in **MS SQL Server**.

This query returns `'6BDA'`

```
SELECT (SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(64), HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', CAST(12.5 AS VARCHAR(64))), 2), 61, 4)) as tmp
```

But when I try to cast it to an int this results in an error:

```
--Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '6BDA' to data type int.
SELECT (CONVERT(int, SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(64), HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', CAST(12.5 AS VARCHAR(64))), 2), 61, 4))) as tmp
```

If I try to convert the substring to varbinary and then to int, the result differs from 27610:

```
--Returns 910312513
SELECT (CONVERT(int, CONVERT(varbinary, SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(64), HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', CAST(12.5 AS VARCHAR(64))), 2), 61, 4)))) as tmp
```

In **Snowflake** I can easily perform the conversion with a `to_number` function:

The below query converts `'6BDA'` to 27610. How can I achieve the same result with SQL Server?

```
SELECT to_number(substr(sha2(TO_VARCHAR(ABS(12.5)), 256), 61), 'xxxx')
```

Comment: I'm not sure of your actual use case but if you need an integer rather than a strirng, you could use `CAST(CAST(SUBSTRING(HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', CAST(12.5 AS VARCHAR(64))),31,2) AS varbinary(4)) AS int)`

Answer (score 1):

Try this out

```
SELECT CAST( CONVERT(VARBINARY,'0x'+RIGHT('00000000'+REPLACE(tmp,'x',''),8),1) AS INT)
from table1
```

I tested it with the following DDL:

```
create table table1(tmp varchar(64));

insert into table1
SELECT SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(64), HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', CAST(12.5 AS VARCHAR(64))), 2), 61, 4)
```

See how it works in [this Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/3aedd0/2).

Comment: I've also tried this query and it worked (added 2 as [Binary style](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)). Which approach is preferable in your opinion? `SELECT (CONVERT(int, CONVERT(varbinary, SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(64), HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', CAST(12.5 AS VARCHAR(64))), 2), 61, 4), 2))) as tmp`

Comment: If speed is a factor, I would test both and pick the faster. If not, pick the one you think is more readable.